# Does ListInstance QuickLaunchUrl work?

Tags: sharepoint

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx):

> QuickLaunchUrl Optional Text.
>   Specifies the URL of the view page to
>   open for the list through Quick Launch
>   navigation.

I then have the following elements with a mixture of valid and invalid URLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00BFEA71-D1CE-42de-9C63-A44004CE0104"
        TemplateType="104"
        Title="Announcements"
        Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="Lists/Invalid/JunkUrl.php">
  </ListInstance>
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106"
        TemplateType="106"
        Title="$Resources:core,calendarList"
        Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder"
        QuickLaunchUrl="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder/AllItems.aspx">
  </ListInstance>
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105"
        TemplateType="105"
        Title="$Resources:core,contactsList;"
        Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,contacts_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="blah blah blah">
  </ListInstance>
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108"
        TemplateType="108"
        Title="Discussions"
        Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,discussions_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="Lists/Team%20Discussion/Threaded.aspx">
  </ListInstance>
  <!-- Custom Shared Documents -->
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="58c1f9c9-eadb-41dd-a358-e04b2f2e30c0"
        TemplateType="100316"
        Title="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Title;"
        Url="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Folder;/Forms/ByCategory.aspx">
  </ListInstance>
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103"
        TemplateType="103"
        Title="$Resources:core,linksList;"
        Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,links_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="FALSE">
  </ListInstance>
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00BFEA71-A83E-497E-9BA0-7A5C597D0107"
        TemplateType="107"
        Title="$Resources:core,taskList;"
        Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,tasks_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="Lists/Tasks/active.aspx">
  </ListInstance>
  <ListInstance
        FeatureId="00BFEA71-C796-4402-9F2F-0EB9A6E71B18"
        TemplateType="119"
        Title="Wiki"
        Url="$Resources:core,WikiWebLibPages_Folder;"
        QuickLaunchUrl="$Resources:core,WikiWebLibPages_Folder;/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

All of the lists appear on the Quick Launch (even the Links list), but none of them (even when valid) are using the custom URL. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, no, QuickLaunchUrl does not work. Use OnQuickLaunch instead.

Using the [documentation](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), I found the following code in Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListInstanceElement:

```
internal SPList EnsureListExists(SPWeb web)
{
    SPList list = null;
    try
    {
        list = web.Lists[this.Title];
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        Guid guid;
        int num;
        string str;
        string documentTemplate;
        SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions off = SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions.Off;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TemplateType))
        {
            num = int.Parse(this.TemplateType, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            str = base.FeatureDefinition.Id.ToString();
            documentTemplate = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FeatureId))
            {
                str = this.FeatureId;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DocumentTemplate))
            {
                documentTemplate = this.DocumentTemplate;
            }
            if (SPUtility.StsCompareStrings(this.OnQuickLaunch, "TRUE") || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.QuickLaunchUrl))
            {
                off = SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions.On;
            }
            guid = web.Lists.Add(this.Title, this.Description, this.Url, str, num, documentTemplate, off);
            if (!(guid != Guid.Empty))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return web.Lists[guid];
        }
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

So putting any value into QuickLaunchUrl has the same effect as entering TRUE into OnQuickLaunch. But I cannot find anywhere that uses or applies the actual value of QuickLaunchUrl.